# Evaluating probability that a player wins the game

Tags: probability

> Players $P_1,P_2,P_3,...,P_m$ of equal skill,play a game consecutively in pairs as $P_1P_2,P_2P_3,P_3P_4,...,P_{m-1}P_m,P_mP_1,P_1P_2 \text{ and so on}...$, and any player who wins two consecutive games(i.e. $k$ and $(k+1)th$ game) wins the match.The question is to find $P_r$ where $P_r$ is the probability that player $P_r$ wins the match.

I tried to figure find out a recursion.$$P_r=(1-P_{r-1})\frac14$$ The probability that $P_r$ wins the match is same as the probability that $P_{r-1}$ loses the match and $P_r$ wins the next two successive matches.However I am not sure of the recursion and could not find the general formula.

Comment: Can you clarify the premise of your question? As in, considering say P3, the probability will depend on the number of matches he has played, i.e. P2P3, P3P4, P2P3....and so on?

Comment: Whoever wins two matches consecutively wins the game.So in my view $P3$ alone should not depend on number of matches he has played.

Comment: This is not clear to me.  So, are you allowing multiple winners (e.g., player 2 wins against 1 and 3 and player 5 wins against 4 and 6)? What happens after $P_mP_1$ (what do the "..." mean?) ? Does it cycle? You seem to be using $P_i$ to represent both a player and that player's probability of winning: perhaps it would be better to use different symbols for these two different things.  Any clarification you could add would be great!

Comment: @MatthewConroy The series of games cycles.See the edit.Only criteria for a player to win the game if it it should win two consecutive matches

Comment: And by winning, the match ends, right? So if player 2 wins the first two pairings, the game is over right?

Comment: @MatthewConroy yes you got it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\omega$ be a random variable equal to the number of winnder.

Your solution has two misses. At first you are trying to compute $p_k$ that is probability that game ends after $k$ matches. Then the probability of $r$th player win is $P\{\omega = r\} = p_r + p_{r + m} + p_{r + 2m} + \cdots$, not just $p_r$.

Secondly if game continues after $k - 1$ matches with probability $1 - p_{k - 1}$ then it can end after $k$ matches with unknown probability, because this probability doesn't give us information about the result of the last $(k - 1)$th match, and the conditional probability that it was won by player who continues playing is not $\frac12$ in general. (EDIT: Events "the game doesn't end after $k - 1$ matches" and "the game ends after $k$ matches" are not independent at all, since they share a subevent.)

For simplicity we will say that $P_i$ and $P_j$ is the same player if $i \equiv j \pmod m$.

Now it is easy to see that general game process is the following: $P_1$ wins $P_2$, $P_2$ wins $P_3$, $\ldots$, $P_{k - 1}$ wins $P_k$, $P_k$ wins $P_{k + 1}$, $P_{k + 2}$ wins $P_{k + 1}$, $P_{k + 3}$ wins $P_{k + 2}$, $\ldots$, $P_{\ell - 1}$ wins $P_{\ell - 2}$, $P_{\ell}$ wins $P_{\ell - 1}$, $P_{\ell}$ wins $P_{\ell + 1}$, game ends after $\ell$ matches. (It is possible that $k = 0$. Note that $\ell \ge k + 2 \ge 2$.) Probability of this event for given $k$ is obviously $\frac{1}{2^{\ell}}$. And $k$ can be $0, 1, \ldots, \ell - 2$, so we have $\ell - 1$ ways to choose $k$. Then $p_{\ell} = \frac{\ell - 1}{2^{\ell}}$.

Now it's time to compute the desired probability of $r$th player's win:
$$P\{\omega = r\} = p_r + p_{r + m} + p_{r + 2m} + \ldots\\
= \sum_{i = 0}^{+\infty} p_{r + i\cdot m} = \sum_{i = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{r + i\cdot m - 1}{2^{r + i\cdot m}}\\
= \frac{m}{2^r}\sum_{i = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{i}{(2^m)^i} + \frac{r - 1}{2^r}\sum_{i = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(2^m)^i}\\
= \frac{m}{2^r}\sum_{i = 0}^{+\infty} \sum_{j = 0}^{i - 1} \frac{1}{(2^m)^i} + \frac{r - 1}{2^r}\cdot\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2^m}}\\
= \frac{m}{2^r}\sum_{0 \le j < i} \frac{1}{(2^m)^i} + \frac{r - 1}{2^r}\cdot\frac{2^m}{2^m - 1}\\
= \frac{m}{2^r}\sum_{j = 0}^{+\infty} \sum_{i = j + 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(2^m)^i} + \frac{2^m(r - 1)}{2^r(2^m - 1)}\\
= \frac{m}{2^r}\sum_{j = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(2^m)^{j + 1}}\cdot\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2^m}} + \frac{2^{m - r}(r - 1)}{2^m - 1}\\
= \frac{m}{2^r}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2^m}}\right)^2\cdot\frac{1}{2^m} + \frac{2^{m - r}(r - 1)}{(2^m - 1)}\\
= \frac{m}{2^r}\cdot\frac{2^m}{\left(2^m - 1\right)^2} + \frac{2^{m - r}(r - 1)}{2^m - 1}.$$
(Note that $P_1$ can't end game after the first match and we should exclude summand $p_1$ from $P\{\omega = 1\}$, but $p_1 = 0$ so its exclusion wouldn't change anything.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I couldnot get how you reached from $$\frac{m}{2^r}\sum_{i = 0}^{+\infty} \sum_{j = 0}^{i - 1} \frac{1}{(2^m)^i} + \frac{r - 1}{2^r}\cdot\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2^m}}$$ to 
$$ \frac{m}{2^r}\sum_{0 \le j < i} \frac{1}{(2^m)^i} + \frac{r - 1}{2^r}\cdot\frac{2^m}{2^m - 1}$$ and the following step
$$ \frac{m}{2^r}\sum_{j = 0}^{+\infty} \sum_{i = j + 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(2^m)^i} + \frac{2^m(r - 1)}{2^r(2^m - 1)}$$Can you please explain a bit on these steps.

Comment: I hope there is no problem with the second summand. Concerning the first one note that $\sum_{i = 0}^{+\infty} \sum_{j = 0}^{i - 1} f(i, j)$ is the sum of $f(i, j) = \frac{1}{(2^m)^i}$ over all $0 \le i$ and $0 \le j \le i - 1$ that is the same as $0 \le j < i$ for integer $i$ and $j$. This inequality I use as condition of summation in the second line: $\sum_{0 \le j < i}f(i, j)$. Further I unfold this sum into double sum again, but I change the order of summation: $f(i, j)$ for $0 \le j$ and $j + 1 \le i$. (Changing order or summation is possible since all summands are positive.)

Answer (score 3):

I'll change the matches sequence slightly, to hopefully make the formulae simpler. So I'll assume the matches go:

$Pm-P1,P1-P2,P2-P3,P3-P4,...,Pm-P1$

That is, the first player that may win is $P1$.

Let's denote the probability that the $j$th player wins in the first round, by $p_j$, and the total probability that the $j$th player wins by $P_j$

We'll further code the match winner as $0$ if the first player wins, and $1$ if the second player wins.

So the tournament may be represented by a string of bits, and it ends when we have a sequence of $[01]$, example (first row is the bit index, second row is the bits sequence, a case with the 5th player winnig):

```
 0123 45
[0011 10]
```

Note that, except for the last $0$, every $0$ must be preceded by a $0$, otherwise the string would stop. It is clearer if we look at the first few cases.

So that $i=1$ wins (in the first round) there is one only sequence

```
10
```

we have $p_1=\frac{1}{2^2}$

So that $i=2$ wins (in the first round) there are two

```
0 10
1 10
```

we have $p_2=\frac{2}{2^3}$

So that $i=3$ wins (in the first round) there are three

```
00 10
01 10
11 10
```

we have $p_3=\frac{3}{2^4}$

The pattern is clear, so:

$p_j=\frac{j}{2^{j+1}}$

Noting that

$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{i}{2^i} = 2-\frac{n+1}{2^{n-1}}$ (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Some_summations_involving_exponential_terms))

we may confirm that

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}p_i= \frac12 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{i}{2^i} =1$

I was tempted to say that winning on any successive round is directly proportional to $p_j$ on the first round, so we could get the total probability by normalising the first round's, but it is not so.

The best I can think of is doing the summation, for all rounds, long and boring, but not really hard (uses another formula from the same source, for the second summation).

$P_j = \sum_{r=0}^\infty p_{j+m\times r}$

$P_j = \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{j}{2^{j+m\times r +1}} + \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{m\times r}{2^{j+m\times r +1}}$

$P_j = \frac{1}{2^{j+1}}\left( \frac{j}{1-\frac1{2^m}} + m \frac{\frac1{2^m}}{ \left(1-\frac1{2^m}\right)^2 }\right)$

$P_j = \frac{1}{2^{j+1}}\left(\frac{ 2^m(2^m-1)j + 2^m m}{ \left(2^m-1\right)^2 }\right)$

Which does add up to one (so hopefully, now it is correct). Examples,

```
For 3 players

j    Pj
-------
1  0.408
2  0.347
3  0.245


For 7 players

j   Pj
-------
1  0.266
2  0.259
3  0.192
4  0.128
5  0.080
6  0.048
7  0.028
```

Comment: Events "$P_1$ doesn't win at least one of two matches" and "$P_2$ wins two matches" are not independent!

Comment: Ooops. You are correct. For now I redacted the wrong solution, tomorrow I'll see if I either can use a similar reasoning and update, or not and delete. Thank you.

Comment: @Smylic Couldn't sleep, thinking about it. Too tired to double check :-) I hope it is fine now

Comment: Hm, you just rewrote my answer...

Comment: @Smylic: I have not rewrote your answer. I wrote my answer. If they get to the same result that is fine, goes for the likelihood that they are both correct. The way I set up the problem is much simpler (to me) without conditional probabilities, just setting up a simple way to count favourable events. Also the final summation is simpler, no double summations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Very nice use of sequences.Can you please attach a proof of the formula you used for the summation.I couldnot find it.

Comment: @navinstudent: I used the formula from the quoted wikipedia page. That page has no proof, nor any reference for the formula, unfortunately. Most of the WP page is referenced from a similar one at [planetmath.org](http://planetmath.org/summation), but this summation is not there. Fortunately, unreferenced or not, it seems to be correct :-)